# Does anyone know why is my table only display the third data when I tried to display it on laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

So, I wanted to display all of my data in my table, my table name is taglineImageCarousel, the problem here is on the slide_ID, where it is filled with data of slide-01, slide-02, and slide-03

and here is the code

taglineImageCarouselController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\taglineImageCarousel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class taglineImageCarouselController extends Controller
{
    // Controller untuk menampilkan data tabel taglineImageCarousel di dashboard
    // landing page
    function index()
    {
        $taglineImage = DB::table('taglineImageCarousel')->get();
        return view('pages.landingpage.landingpage', ['taglineImage' => $taglineImage]);
    }
}
```

Then I put the route code in my web.php file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\taglineImageCarouselController;
Route::get('/landingpage', [taglineImageCarouselController::class, 'index']);
```

I also already create the model file called taglineImageCarousel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class taglineImageCarousel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Finally, I tried to display the data in my landingpage.blade.php, where it is located in the file of views/pages/landingpage/landingpage.blade.php

```
                            <?php 
                                    foreach ($taglineImage as $tagline) 
                                    {
                                        $id         = $tagline->slide_ID;
                                        $status      = $tagline->status;
                                    }
                                ?>

                                <tbody> <!--Isi Tabel -->
                                    @foreach($taglineImage as $tagline)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $status; ?></td>
                                        <td><a href=Home.html>detail</a></td> 
                                    </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tbody>
```

When I run it, it will shows a table that only filled with the slide-03 data (which is the third data in my table). Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you on `/landingpage` when viewing? Might be a different URL that uses the same view. Try `dd($taglineImage)` in your method

Comment: Ok so now I tried to directly go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/landingpage. But it seems that I get different error message, which is "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array (View: D:\yummycorp-web-admin\resources\views\pages\landingpage\landingpage.blade.php)"

Comment: It's an object, not an array. So use `$tagline->slide_ID` ... instead of `$tagline['slide_ID']`

Comment: Sorry as I am not quite understand, so do I need to type it like this? <td>{{$tagline->'slide_ID'}}</td> since it will gives me an error syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string "slide_ID", expecting identifier or variable or "{" or "$"

Comment: Ok I finally got it, it seems that I just need to remove the '', so it will become <td>{{$tagline->slide_ID}}</d>

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems that thanks to brombeer advice, I just need to rewrite my landingblade.php code to

```
                                <tbody> 
                                @foreach($taglineImage as $tagline)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$tagline->slide_ID}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$tagline->status}}</td>
                                    <td><a href=Home.html>detail</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
```